# Active class siblings removeClass

Tags: jquery

I have various elements which have the class `.folder`

When I click one I want to add the class `active` to it and remove the class from any other element.

The problem is removing the class from the others first, its simply not doing it.

Here's what I'm trying:

```
$('.folder').click(function() {
    $(this).siblings('.folder').removeClass('active'); // remove from all other <SPAN>s
    $(this).addClass('active'); // add onto current
})
```

Example HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li class="closed last">
        <span class="folder" id="16">More coding</span>
    </li>
</ul>  
</li>
<li class="closed collapsable lastCollapsable">
    <span class="folder active" id="12">Music</span>
    <ul style="display: block;" id="browser" class="filetree treeview-famfamfam">
        <li class="closed collapsable">
            <span class="folder active" id="13">Music child</span>
                <ul style="display: block;" id="browser" class="filetree treeview-famfamfam">
                    <li class="closed last">
                        <span class="folder" id="15">More music</span>
                    </li>
                </ul>
         </li>
         <li class="closed last"><span class="folder" id="17">Another child here</span> </li>
     </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Can you show your HTML? My guess is that they are not siblings.

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon I think you're right - should I use .find instead maybe

Comment: @ConnorBlack Added html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my opinion, remove class from all elements

```
$('.folder').click(function() {
    $('.folder.active').removeClass('active'); // Just remove class from all folder
    $(this).addClass('active'); // add onto current
})
```

Answer (score 0):

simple and effective :

```
$('.folder').click(function() {
    $('span .folder').removeClass('active'); // remove from all other <SPAN>s
    $(this).addClass('active'); // add onto current
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Here 3 possibles solution.

One basic :

```
$('span.folder').click(function() {
    $('.folder').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
})
```

One a little bit faster:

```
$('.folder').click(function() {
    $('span.folder.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
})
```

The fastest but wont work if there is other elements with `.active`:

```
$('.folder').click(function() {
    $('.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
})
```

JsPerf : http://jsperf.com/three-solutions