# JQuery detect if current element has previous sibling

Tags: jquery, html

I need to swap classes on some `section` elements and cannot work out how to detect that whether a `section` that has a class of `active` has a previous sibling or not.

HTML:

```
<div id="slider">
    <section class="element active"><section>
    <section class="element"><section>
    <section class="element"><section>
    <section class="element"><section>
</div>
```

JQuery

```
$('.nav-left').bind('click', function(){
    var section = $('[data-spark-section]'),
        currentSection = $('section.element.active');
    if($(currentSection).prev('section')){
        console.log(true);
        //Add Class to previous & remove from current
    }else{
        console.log(false);
        //Do Nothing
    }
    console.log(currentSection);
});
```

The question is **not** about how to swap classes but indeed how best to detect whether an element has a previous sibling.

Answered by [@satpal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1668533/satpal) by checking the `.length`

```
if($(currentSection).prev('section').length){//exists}
```

Comment: Check `length` property i.e. `if(currentSection.prev('section').length){//exists}`. Actually you don't need to check if it exist just use `currentSection.prev('section').addClass('active')` if the element exists the class will be added

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Active class siblings removeClass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19200617/active-class-siblings-removeclass)